# How do I highlight a specific day on the calendar retrieved from the URL?

Tags: javascript, css, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar to allow the user to select a specific date, retrieve data from a database, then reload the page with that data.  The page is being rewritten with the selected date in the URL.

On reload, I get the date and load the calendar using the defaultDate param and it moves to the selected date, but there is no visual highlighting of the selected day.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var newDate = getUrlVars()["scheduled_date"];
    // console.log(newDate);

    $('#scheduled_calendar').fullCalendar({

        <!--Header Section Including Previous,Next and Today-->
        header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },

        <!--Default Date-->
        // defaultDate: '2015-02-12',
        defaultDate: newDate,
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events


        dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
            // console.log(date.format());
            var currentUrl = window.location.href;

            $(".fc-state-highlight").removeClass("fc-state-highlight");
            $(this).addClass("fc-state-highlight");

            newURL = addURLParam(currentUrl,"scheduled_date", date.format())
            location.href = newURL;
        }

    });

    if (newDate > "0000-00-00") {
        $('#scheduled_calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', newDate);
    }
});
```

Comment: be aware that `<!-- this is a HTML comment -->` while `// this` and `/* this */` are **valid** JS comments.

Comment: Can you provide a working demo?

Answer (score 0):

Found something that works. Edited the final if statement.

```
    if (newDate > "0000-00-00") {
        $('#scheduled_calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', newDate);

        $('.fc-day[data-date="' + newDate + '"]').css('background-color', "lightcyan");
    }
```

Can't find the .fc-day object in the documentation though.